# How to setup Three.js for asp.net MVC project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, three.js, blender

I am having the hardest time getting something up and running with three.js just to load a simple blender file. I tried following the [installation](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation) guide and installed using NPM. I have the following so far in my home index view.

```
<script type="module">
   // Option 1: Import the entire three.js core library.
   import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three';
   const scene = new THREE.Scene();
</script>
```

I included the files in my project that were installed with NPM:

[image]

When I load the page however I keep getting a 403 error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find examples of implementing with Visual Studio / .Net. I typically use Nuget and don't have much experience with NPM so perhaps I just did something incorrectly?